# Lattice Diamond timing errors in place and route with large registers

Tags: fpga, verilog, lattice

Is there a good way to generate a timer with at least 27bits of precision so the place and route doesn't fail? I've tried breaking up the timers into 4x8 bit timers, but it only makes the slack worse (-5 or so). With this design the worst timing slack is -1.600.

I get +2.600 if I use this code as a single 16 bit timer and +5.400 with a single 8 bit timer.

I'm using Lattice Diamond 3.12, with the LSE synthesizer.

Chip: LCMXO3L-6900C-5BG256C

Clock: 133Mhz

```
`include "C:/lscc/diamond/3.12/cae_library/simulation/verilog/machxo3l/OSCH.v"


module system_clock(clock);
    output wire clock;
    defparam OSCH_inst.NOM_FREQ = "133";  
    OSCH OSCH_inst( 
        .STDBY(1'b0), // 0=Enabled, 1=Disabled
        .OSC(clock),
        .SEDSTDBY()
        );
    
endmodule

module pgen(trigger, pulse);
    input wire trigger;
    output reg pulse;
    
    reg [31:0]pr = 32'hffff_ffff;
    reg [31:0]tmr = 32'b0;
    
    wire CLK;
    system_clock sysclk(CLK);
    
    
    reg trigger_pre = 1'b0;
    reg run_en = 1'b0;
    always @(posedge CLK)begin
        trigger_pre <= trigger;
        
        if(trigger && !trigger_pre)begin
            run_en <= 1'b1;
            pulse <= 1'b1;
        end
        
        if(run_en)begin
            if(tmr == pr)begin
                pulse <= 1'b0;
                run_en <= 1'b0;
            end
            else begin
                tmr = tmr + 32'b1;
            end
        end
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Why do you compare with pr? Just let the counter overflow on its own.

Comment: did you try the built-in counter generatable via  "ip express"? I just did a quick&dirty test with that and the timing analysis looks fine to me using that counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic circuit is a register and an adder, and you're running out of time when the carry chain in the adder gets to be too long.

```
constant -+            +----------+
          |            |          |
          v            v          |
    +-----------------------+     |
    |   32-bit adder        |     |
    +-----------------------+     |
                |                 |
                v                 |
    +-----------------------+     |
    |  32-bit accumulator   |     |
    +-----------------------+     |
                |                 |
                +-----------------+
                |
                v
```

One basic technique for addressing this kind of problem is to pipeline the adder.

```
    constant ---------+       +-------+
    low half          |       |       |
                      v       v       |
                   +--------------+   |
                   | 16-bit adder |   |
                   +--------------+   |
                      |       |       |
                      v       v       |
                   +--------------+   |
                   | 16-bit acc.  |   |
                   +--------------+   |
               carry |        | sum   |
                 out |        +-------+
                     |        | sum
                     v        v
            +-------------------------+
            |   pipeline register     |
constant    +-------------------------+
high                 |        |
half --+       +----------+   |
       |       |     |    |   |
       v       v     |    |   |
   +--------------+  |    |   |
   | 16-bit adder |<-+    |   |
   +--------------+ carry |   |
            |       in    |   |
            v             |   |
    +--------------+      |   |
    | 16-bit acc.  |      |   |
    +--------------+      |   |
            |             |   |
            +-------------+   |
            |                 |
            v                 v
```

Obviously, this adds a clock of latency to the calculation, but it still produces a result every clock. Often, the rest of the logic can be adjusted to account for the extra latency.

I once did this in an FPGA that was so slow that I could only add two bits at a time in one clock cycle. I built a 22-bit delta-sigma modulator (11 stages) to produce a PWM output that controlled an external VCXO to high precision. Since I only needed the MSB of the result, the pipelining added little overhead.

Answer (score 0):

First how fast is your clock?  If you can slow that down it will solve your problem of course.

Second, in general my thought was to suggest a second registered copy of your timer (tmrQ) and run your comparison on that (tmrQ==pr). That said since PR is hard coded I’m not convinced that will help, but it might.

A third general idea is to have multiple timers running at different clock rates.  Split the problem into a small timer running at a fast rate and a larger timer running at a slower rate.  This fundamentally reduces the “work” done per cycle at the faster rate.  Use properly constrained pll derived clocks.

Comment: I added a few more details, 133MHz is the clock frequency. Unfortunately, I need the higher frequency to set the output resolution. The period register (PR) will not be hard coded in the end. This is just a test to get figure out the timing issue.